# findOneAndUpdate() used on two different ObjectIds, but updates only one

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm building an API that pushes follower and following to two arrays in user objects.
I'm trying to use `findOneAndUpdate()` for this but it only updates the elements in one object.

```
  let userToFollow = req.body.following;
  let userThatfollows = req.body.follower;

  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    userToFollow,
    { $push: { followers: userThatfollows } },
    { new: true, upsert: true },
    function (err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    }
  );
  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    userThatfollows,
    { $push: { following: userToFollow } },
    { new: true, upsert: true },
    function (err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    }
  );
```

I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: what data are you passing in userToFollow and userThatfollows?

Comment: user id's i.e ObjectId of the user in database

Comment: did you check the err value inside callback? is it throwing any error?